# Loop through .txt files in a folder and search for certain characters in the file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file, text

How can I loop through `.dbl and` `.txt` files in a folder, find `.txt` files with a specific number and condition (e.g. 'laser on') and then do things to the associated `.dbl` file (if the names are similar)?

I don't really have much and I can't seem to access the file names I want to look through using `getfield(files, 'name')` so I'm really stuck. Here is what I have so far so as to give some more structure to my question.

```
% specify folder with the load function to manipulate .dbl files
folder = 'some folder';

% specify folder that has the data
folder2 = 'some other folder';

cd(folder);
addpath(folder2);

% specify parameters implemented in data collection program
start_delay = 0; % in ps
step_size = 20; % in ps
n_steps = 30;

% loop through folders
files = dir(folder2);
for i = 1:size(files,1)
    if i == '*.txt
    % find string 'ON'
    % find a number in .txt file
    % for .txt files with string 'ON', look for .txt files for delay =0, then 20, then 40, etc.
    % find associated .dbl file 
    % manipulate .dbl file
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The things you are looking for are the `*.xxx` comand for `dir` and `strfind`, take a look at this example:

```
txtList=dir('*.txt');
sblList=dir('*.dbl');

for ii=1:length(txtList)

    fid=fopen(txtList(ii).name); 
    C= textscan(fid,'%s'); %depends on your formating
    C=C{1}{1}; %supposing you .txt is really just one string
    fclose(fid);

    if (sum(strfind(C,'ON'))) %for .txt files with string 'ON'...

        Equals0=strfind(C,'0'); % ... look for =0,...
        Equals20=strfind(C,'20'); %then =20
        %... etc

    end

    %you get the idea...
    %do whatever you want with dblList

end
```